# Finding near by lat long from database

Tags: nearest-neighbor

I have a relational db storing location in lat and long format. Based on a current given point, I have to find the locations from the db that are within "x" kms from the given location. Any pointers how to start with? Places API?

Comment: Wich DBMS are you using? At least on Microsoft SQL Server you have geographic functions: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx

Answer (score 0):

On Microsoft SQL Server you have [geographic functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280766.aspx). You could use an T-SQL script like this:

```
DECLARE @givenLatitude float
      , @givenLongitude float
      , @givenLocation geography
      , @maximumDistance float ;

SET @givenLatitude = ... ;
SET @givenLongitude = ... ;

SET @givenLocation = geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST(@givenLongitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                                                          CAST(@givenLatitude AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326) ;

SELECT *
FROM Locations
WHERE geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(' + CAST([Longitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ' ' + 
                                           CAST([Latitude] AS VARCHAR(20)) + ')', 4326)
                .STDistance(@givenLocation) <= @maximumDistance ;
```